# Youtube-dl error message: Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl

I want to download a video with youtubedl

I have my options to set to:

```
ydl_opts = {
    'verbose': False,
    'ignoreerrors': True,
    'cachedir': None,
    'outtmpl': "%(title)s.%(ext)s",
    'format': 'm4a/bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{ 
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'm4a',
    }]
}
```

But the program gives me this error

```
[download] Got error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden 
ERROR: fragment 1 not found, unable to continue
```

I am on the latest version youtube-dl available with pip.

I tried to add a referrer because I read that might work from a previous post, but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: Is this the cause? https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/32495

Answer (score 2):

Youtube-DL hasn't received official updates in two years according to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/#history).

It's generally recommended to utilize one of the forks instead. Look at [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (here is it's [release history](https://pypi.org/project/yt-dlp/#history)).

yt-dlp is generally considered a drop-in replacement for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer directly to your question, but you can use Pytube. Like so:

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/2lAe1cqCOXo')
```

Now you can get a list of available streams, for example:

```
print (f'mp4 streams:\n{yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4'})
print (f'audio streams:\n{yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True)})
```

Now choose the stream you want to download from the options you just got (replace `itag` with whatever one you want):

```
stream = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
```

And download it:

```
stream.download(filename=yt.title)
```